why doesn't a custom Angular library compile once published on npm?
I released a library that I developed for the team I work for. The idea is to have an accelerator in creating applications dedicated to the IOT sector. I have a problem, the library in the demo project (same repository) has no compilation problems, but once published on npm and installed on a project (ng17) it doesn't compile and I have the error you see in the image.
Does anyone know how to help me? I've already tried setting aliases with no success.
@avvale/ngx-iot is public and downloadable if you want to try it too.
Error:

Don't have the compilation problem by using @avvale in the library name as the company that maintains it is the goal

My guess is that  @avvale/ngx-iot isn't a dependency in package.json , so it doesn't get installed by npm and your code can't find it.

FIXED: The build output and consequently the files to export have changed.


"exports": {
"./inputs": {
"types": "./inputs/index.d.ts",
"esm2022": "./inputs/esm2022/ngx-iot-inputs.mjs",
"esm": "./inputs/esm2022/ngx-iot-inputs.mjs",
"default": "./inputs/fesm2022/ngx-iot-inputs.mjs"
},
"./cognito": {
"types": "./cognito/ngx-iot-cognito.d.ts",
"esm2022": "./cognito/esm2022/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs",
"esm2020": "./cognito/esm2020/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs",
"es2020": "./cognito/fesm2020/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs",
"es2015": "./cognito/fesm2015/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs",
"node": "./cognito/fesm2015/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs",
"default": "./cognito/fesm2020/ngx-iot-cognito.mjs"
},



the first block is the right one, the second is the one that didn't work
